# Multipart/Mixed Chunked MIME Response: Convert to single files

Tags: java, grails, groovy

A webservice returns a MIME file as InputStream with following content. I use Java Apache HTTPClient in order to make a request:

```
MIME-Version:1.0
Content-Type:multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_58_1750763977.1605815692305"

------=_Part_58_1750763977.1605815692305
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=preview.pdf
Content-ID: response-1
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=preview.pdf

%PDF-1.7
[...]
```

```
------=_Part_67_626667127.1605818243111
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=thumbnail.jpg
Content-ID: response-2
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=thumbnail.jpg
```

```
------=_Part_58_1750763977.1605815692305
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=report.xml
Content-ID: response-3
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=report.xml
```

How can I now convert these chunks to single files? I tried javax.Mail and MIME file, but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to parse the message as mime and save the attachments as file:

```
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    Session s = Session.getInstance(new Properties());
    MimeMessage myMessage = new MimeMessage(s, response.getEntity().getContent());
    Multipart multipart = (Multipart) myMessage.getContent();
    for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
        BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
        InputStream is = bodyPart.getInputStream();
        File f = new File("tmp/" + bodyPart.getFileName());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while((bytesRead = is.read(buf))!=-1) {
            fos.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        fos.close();
    }
```

by using

```
compile([group: 'tech.blueglacier', name: 'email-mime-parser', version: '1.0.5'])
```